# Why do Properties load method failed in Eclipse plugin dev?

Tags: java, properties, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to use [Properties's `load()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29) method in my Eclipse plugin project. Since I wanna put the propertie file in a folder like this:

```
Pluging Project/
               |
               +----/src/...   
               +----/config/config.properties
               +----/icons/...
               +----META-IN/
               +----build.properties
               +----plugin.xml
```

And then I try code like this but **failed**:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream inputStream = (InputStream) Activator.getDefault().getBundle().getEntry("/config/config.properties").getContent();
prop.load(inputStream);
```

This method receipt a input byte stream as parameter. And I'm pretty sure `Activator.getDefault().getBundle().getEntry()` returns a InputStream.
And if I put the propertie file in the same location of the calling class and use

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
```

It will go well.

So any hints?

Comment: Have you tried using [openStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) instead of `getContent()` of `URL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `URL` returned by `Bundle.getEntry` uses an internal Eclipse scheme and doesn't always support `getContents()`. You need to call `org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.toFileURL()` to convert it:

```
URL url = Activator.getDefault().getBundle().getEntry("/config/config.properties");

url = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);

InputStream inputStream = (InputStream)url.getContent();
```

Also make sure you have the `config` directory listed in the `build.properties`